# PHP_SELF not equating

Tags: php, include, superglobals

I'm trying to code a sidebar for my website. For this, I store pairs of values corresponding to the links in a file, say names.txt:

```
Home-index.php
Coding-coding.php
```

and my php file will then take these values and turn them into links on the side, i.e.

```
<a href = "index.php">Home</a>
<a href = "coding.php">Coding</a>
```

And so forth. Now, I want to make it so that, for the page that i'm on, instead of displaying a hyperlink, it will display a bold version of the text.
i.e. if i was on index.php, it outputs

```
<strong>Home</strong>
<a href = "coding.php">Coding</a>
```

To do this, i use `explode` to split my strings from the file, and then `PHP_SELF` to detect whether it is the same page.

On top of this, since the script will be in different pages, I put that into a file (side.php) and then used `include('side.php')`. Inside side.php there is the sidebar function, which takes the page directory (via `PHP_SELF`) as an argument. Everything else works fine, except for the bold-text. Help?

P.S. When i say `PHP_SELF` I mean `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Thanks!

(My code, or part thereof...)

In side.php:

```
<?php
    function sidebar($input){
        # echo ($input);
        $sitenav = fopen("file","r");
        $amts=0;
        do{
            $sidebarvals[$amts]=fgets($sitenav);
            $amts=$amts+1;
        }while ($sidebarvals[$amts-1]!="EOF");
        $amts--;
        for ($i=0;$i<$amts;$i++){
            $parts = explode("-",$sidebarvals[$i]);
            if ("/" . $parts[1]!=$input){
                echo "<a href=" . $parts[1] .">" . $parts[0] . "</a>";
            }else{
                echo "<strong>" . $parts[0] . "</strong>";
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
        fclose($sitenav);
    }
?>
```

and on each page:

```
include ('side.php'); sidebar($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Comment: You should post the code you are using. The problem is possibly the backslash at the start of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Comment: Well, i tried to do a concatenation of the string using "/" . $namefromfile

Comment: I'll put up my code then.

Comment: Have you done `var_dump()`'s of the relevant variables?

Answer (score 0):

As i Know PHP_SELF returns file name with full file path as index.php will return /index.php. But looks like that you are trying to match index.php against returned value /index.php.
So, in order to correct you must get file name from PHP_SELF and it can be achieved in this way.

```
$url_array = explode('/',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$last = count($url_array) - 1;
$file = url_array[$last];
```

Comment: Well thanks. I am trying to do it by appending "/" to the other part of the string. Why doesn't that work?